# Repeat POSIX quantifier not working in Amazon Redshift

Tags: regex, amazon-redshift

I am sorry to ask this question here. But I could not find anything similar on stackoverflow/google. Please re-direct me if there is an existing documentation.

I am trying to match strings using regular expression using the following syntax:

```
select regexp_substr('2018-09-90 88:88:90:900 -0900','([0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]* (\\+|-)[0-9]*)')
```

It works perfectly and I get an output like:

```
2018-09-90 88:88:90:900 -0900
```

But using `{}` instead of `*` returns `null`.

```
select regexp_substr('2018-09-90 88:88:90:900 -0900','([0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]* (\\+|-)[0-9][0-9]{2,})')
```

Comment: Replace `[0-9]{2,}` with `[0-9][0-9]+`

Comment: Note that if it is BRE POSIX, you should use `[0-9]\{2,\}`. Is it BRE or ERE?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I have to specify the number of digits since I want to use it in where clause to filter out unwanted timestamp patterns. I am not sure whether Redshift is BRE or ERE. I think it is BRE. I tried using \ and \\. Didn't help.

Comment: If `{2,}` and `\{2,\}` do not work the engine does not support limiting quantifiers. You will have to repeat `[0-9]` "manually". Or like `'...' || REPEAT('[0-9]', 2) || '...'`

Comment: The real question is: why on earth are you storing timestamp values in a `varchar` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You confirmed that neither `[0-9]{2,}` nor `[0-9]\{2,\}` work for you.

That means, your regex library does not support it, or it is broken.

To work around it, you may repeat a pattern using `REPEAT`  function:

```
[0-9]{m}    = REPEAT('[0-9]', m)
[0-9]{m,}   = REPEAT('[0-9]', m) || '[0-9]*'
[0-9]{m,n}  = REPEAT('[0-9]', m) || CONCAT(REPEAT('[0-9]?', n-m))
```

Your pattern can easily be re-written as

```
'([0-9]*-[0-9]*-[0-9]* [0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]* [+-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*)'
```

where `[0-9]{2,}` is replaced with `[0-9][0-9][0-9]*` (2 must-be digits and 0 or more to follow).

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor. Although, I didn't need to use the solution you provided as there was some problem with the sql workbench I was using. I tried with RazorSQL and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks again for your time!